# how to include null results in Django ORM queries

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django ORM system. I have model of students where each student has his/her prefered state of work. Like few students wanna work in "Mahrashtra' State and others wanna work in some other state.

Let's suppose I wanna search for those students who have prefered working state as 'California'. I do following query

```
result= Students.object.filter(prefered_state='California')
```

and of course I get desired result but I wanna include even those students in results who haven't yet entered their preferred state. Means students with state as **Null** or **''**. So isn't there any way to specify to include Null results for criteria other than using **OR** statement. As I have many more criteria for many other fields and I don't wanna include OR xyz is null for every field

Answer (score 8):

You could use `Q`. Note that this answer takes into account both NULL values and empty strings.

```
from django.db.models import Q

states = ['California', '']
Item.objects.filter(Q(prefered_state__in=states)|Q(prefered_state__isnull=True))
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way than using Q object's OR expression. I meant I have around 10 other criteria other than prefered_state so I felt it would be better If I could simply use any function OR something like that where I could simply mention I also want to include Null result for each criteria. Thanks anyway

Comment: @PointNetworks, write own function that creates filter for you from Qs. Q is the bottom of abstractions for django ORM.

Answer (score 1):

result= Students.object.filter(Q(prefered_state='California') | Q(prefered_state__isnull=True))

Check out Q object here: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Q

result= Students.object.filter(Q(prefered_state='California')|Q(prefered_state__is_null=True))
```